# Map error in the initialization with static functions

Tags: c++

I tried to understand the error but no idea.
The map looks like this:

`std::map<std::string, IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &)> _func`

And trying to give the value like this:

`_func["int8"] = &Factory::createInt8;`

And how is my class:

```
class Factory
{
public:
    Factory();
    ~Factory();
    static IOperand *createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value);

private:
    std::map<std::string, IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &)> _func;
    static IOperand *createInt8(const std::string &value);
    static IOperand *createInt16(const std::string &value);
    static IOperand *createInt32(const std::string &value);
    static IOperand *createFloat(const std::string &value);
    static IOperand *createDouble(const std::string &value);
    static IOperand *createBigDecimal(const std::string &value);
};
```

And the error:

```
Assigning to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &), std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &)> > >::mapped_type' (aka 'IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &)') from incompatible type 'IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)' (aka 'IOperand *(*)(const basic_string<char> &)')
```

The error is in assigning the value.

Comment: The compiler has written the whole answer for you: the needed type of the map values is `IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)`, not `IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &)`. What does prevent your from changing the map declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value type of the `map` is `IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &)`, which are non-`static` member functions of `Factory`. What you have in your class are `static` member functions. You can fix the problem by changing the value tpe of the `map` or by changing the functions.

#### Option 1

Change the value type.

```
std::map<std::string, IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)> _func;
```

#### Option 2

Change the functions.

```
IOperand *createInt8(const std::string &value);
IOperand *createInt16(const std::string &value);
IOperand *createInt32(const std::string &value);
IOperand *createFloat(const std::string &value);
IOperand *createDouble(const std::string &value);
IOperand *createBigDecimal(const std::string &value);
```

---

I'll let you figure out which one best serves your needs.

Answer (score 4):

`Factory::createInt8` is static member function, the type of `&Factory::createInt8` is not `IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &)`, but `IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)`.

You can change the type of `map` to

```
std::map<std::string, IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)> _func;
```

Or make these functions non-static member functions.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &);
```

describes a pointer to member function.
What you try to assign is a pointer to function.

So, the type of your map should be:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, IOperand *(*)(const std::string &)> _func;
```